# calling method inside itself bad?

Tags: c#, methods

I've been coding a text adventure game. On game start, Menu(string Choice, bool takenDump) is called. There are several few other methods that have different scenarios that the user can run into, such as a pokemon encounter and such. If the user dies, then they restart at Menu(), meaning it is called again from within itself. Is there any way to avoid this?  [Source of program](http://pastebin.ca/2462382)

Comment: This is simply known as recursion, and in your case you are just using it as a kind of looping. Why do you want to avoid it, in particular?

Comment: You can implement some sort of Indexer. The first time the user run the game, it increase its value. When he dies, you pass the current index as a parameter.

Comment: I know this is totally not what you are asking at all but I wanted to recommend a wrapper around your Console.WriteLine's, i usually make nice wrappers that allow me to also specify a color so my text can have different contexts. This will also reduce the amount of code you need to write in order to change colors which is a pain as well as you can have a smaller foot print class. Here is one I wrote feel free to reuse or recreate :) http://snipplr.com/view/66759/console-write-utility/

Comment: I was told that recursing the code was bad, I guess it isn't? The goal is to have the game restart whenever the user dies, and it does that quite well, so no problem then?

Comment: Recursion isn't bad in and of itself (quite the opposite, actually: functional programming, for instance, makes heavy use of recursion). What's important is to know when using it can cause troubles, for example in terms of stack frames. The choice between iteration and recursion can boil down to a matter of choice. Recursion can be written as iteration, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with using it.

Answer (score 4):

As long as there is a condition to exit the loop, there's no problem. If there's not, you basically have an endless loop (until a StackoverflowException occurs).

From a pure technical point of view, there's no problem as long as you break the loop before a stackoverflowexception occurs.

Comment: Some languages use recursion for looping control flow stuctures e.g. http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion

Comment: Indeed, a recursion can be equivalent to a while-loop

Comment: Won't an infinite recursion result in a stack overflow? Unlike an infinite loop, which will not continually add to the call stack.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "as long as there is a condition to exit the loop", provided that this condition occurs before the exception.

Comment: Yes, but you also say "which can also be as intended if you want the game to continue forever". My point is that this will not work so it won't go on "forever". It will only go on untill the stack overflows and kills his process.

Comment: If your language supports something called tail recursion, then it's ok to recurse forever in some circumstances. C# is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is perfectly fine to call method from itself - the name is "recursion" / "recursive function".

In your particular case it is absolutely not necessary (and likely wrong). Top level game code often look like infinite loop rather than recursion:

```
 while (continuePlaying)
 { 
    ResetLevels_Lives_AndEverything(); 
    while(notDead)
    {
       handleInput()
       draw()
       notDead = ChechStillAlive();
    }
    continuePlaying = CheckContinuePlaying();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should watch out for when using recursion is stack overflow. It doesn't seem like an issue in what you're trying to do, but in cases where your method calls itself multiple times, and each of those calls call it multiple times again, it will happen (unless you set a reasonable limit of levels of how deep you go). Think fractals, factorials, Fibonacci sequence.